# Не выводится значение куки на новой странице - php

Tags: php, авторизация, форма

Здравствуйте! Пишу простую форму авторизации по имени пользователя через куки. Однако на новой странице после проверки, не выводиться значение куки - $_COOKIE['cookname']; В чем проблема?

Сначала код первой страницы - setcookie1.php:

```
    <?php
// запускаем процедуру аутентификации пользователя 
if ($_REQUEST[auth] == "no") {
    $msg = "Вы не являетесь пользователем. Пожалуйста, зарегистрируйтесь.";
}

// если пользователь щелкает на кнопке Login, создается cookie, содержащий его имя пользователя и ip-адрес
if ($_POST[submit] == "Login") {
    $cookie_name = "cookname";
    $cookie_value = $_POST[uname];
    $cookie_expire = time() + 14400; 
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $cookie_expire, "/");
    $formDisplay = "no"; // для последующей проверки вывода формы 
}  
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Куки</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font: 10pt arial;
    color: white;
}
div#form {
    background-color: gray;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 10px;
}
input {
    border: solid 2px black; 
}
</style>
<?php
if ($formDisplay == "no")
{
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0, URL=siteaccess.php?auth=yes">
<?php
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="form">
<h4 style = "color: red">Новый пользователь? Создайте имя пользователя</h4>
<form action="setcookie1.php" name="formforcookie" method="post">
<p>Имя пользователя:
<br>
<input type="text" name="uname" size="7">
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">
</form>
<h4 style="color: red">Уже зарегистрированы?
<a style="color: white" href="siteaccess.php?auth=yes">Войти</a></h4> 
</div>
<br>
<br>
<?php
echo "<span style='color: red'>" . $msg . "</span>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Затем второй - siteaccess.php:

```
    <?php
// проверка успешной аутентификации пользователя 
if ($_REQUEST['auth'] == "yes" && $_REQUEST['cookname'] == $_POST['uname']) {
    echo "<meta charset='utf-8'>"; 
    echo "Добро пожаловать, " . htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['cookname']);
    }

else {
    header("Location: setcookie1.php?auth=no");
}
?>
```

Comment: Попробуйте сократить код до минимально необходимого для воспроизведения проблемы. Есть у меня сомнения в том, что дело, например, в CSS.

Comment: Используйте ссылку [edit] для правки своего вопроса вместо создания ответов на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще раз публикую код с предложенными вами исправлениями.

Страница setcookie1.php:

```
<?php
// запускаем процедуру аутентификации пользователя 
if (!empty($_REQUEST["auth"])) {
    $msg = "Вы не являетесь пользователем. Пожалуйста, зарегистрируйтесь.";
}

// если пользователь щелкает на кнопке Login, создается cookie, содержащий его имя пользователя и ip-адрес
if ($_POST['submit'] == "Login") {
    $cookie_name = "cookname";
    $cookie_value = $_POST['uname'];
    $cookie_expire = time() + 14400; 
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $cookie_expire, "/");
    $formDisplay = "no"; // для последующей проверки вывода формы 
}  
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Куки</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font: 10pt arial;
    color: white;
}
div#form {
    background-color: gray;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 10px;
}
input {
    border: solid 2px black; 
}
</style>
<?php
if ($formDisplay == "no")
{
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0, URL=siteaccess.php?auth=yes">
<?php
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="form">
<h4 style = "color: red">Новый пользователь? Создайте имя пользователя</h4>
<form action="setcookie1.php" name="formforcookie" method="post">
<p>Имя пользователя:
<br>
<input type="text" name="uname" size="7">
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">
</form>
<h4 style="color: red">Уже зарегистрированы?
<a style="color: white" href="siteaccess.php?auth=yes">Войти</a></h4> 
</div>
<br>
<br>
<?php
echo "<span style='color: red'>" . $msg . "</span>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Страница siteaccess.php:

```
<?php
// проверка успешной аутентификации пользователя 
if ($_REQUEST['auth'] == "yes" and isset($_COOKIE['cookname'])) {
    echo "<meta charset='utf-8'>"; 
    echo "Добро пожаловать, " . htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['cookname']);
    }

else {
    header("Location: setcookie1.php?auth=no");
}
```

Как раз проблема возникала из-за html-комментариев, встроенных в самое начало страницы setcookie1.php. Как только я убрал их, скрипт проверки условия заработал верно.

**Большое спасибо Всем за предложенную помощь!**

Comment: ```if (!empty($_COOKIE['cookname'])) {```

Comment: Пожалуйста, разъясните только, почему необходимо использовать функцию empty тут: `if (!empty($_REQUEST['auth'])) {`   вместо того, что я предлагал ранее ?

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу у вас в коде несколько проблем, разной значимости

1. Условие проверки на странице siteaccess.php значительно проще - надо только куку проверить

`if (!empty($_COOKIE['cookname'])) {`

2. Пробелы в начале файлов могут мешать установке кук

`.....<?php`

Необходимо предотвратить вывод любого текста до вызова `setcookie(...)`.
В данном случае удалите пробелы в начале файла и попробуйте ещё раз

3. Предупреждения PHP о синтаксисе могут мешать установке кук

В частности, значения проверять через `isset()` или `empty()` и использовать кавычки для ключей массива, то есть не 
`if ($_REQUEST[auth]) { ... }`, а `if (!empty($_REQUEST["auth"])) { ... }`

[image]

Comment: Это могут быть волшебные 4 пробела, необходимые в нашем сообществе для форматирования текста как кода. Возможно автор долго правил сообщение перед его отправкой. Но с замечанием соглашусь.

Answer (score 1):

С логикой подробно разобраться не пытался, но рекомендовал бы для начала:

1. избавиться от использования суперглобального массива $_REQUEST.
   Во-первых, переменные могут друг друга перекрывать; во-вторых, в
   [настройках](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) может быть отключена возможность записи переменных,
   передаваемых каким-либо определённым методом;
2. при использовании
   текстовых ключей, заключайте их в кавычки. Не `$_REQUEST[auth]`, а
   `$_REQUEST['auth']` – тоже может быть критичным;
3. замечание учатника @copist совершенно справедливо. Куки можно устанавливать до вывода какого-либо содержимого на странице.

Answer (score 0):

Код в начале замените на:

```
if ($_POST['submit'] == "Login") {
$cookie_name = "cookname";
$cookie_value = $_POST['uname'];
$cookie_expire = time() + 14400; 
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $cookie_expire, "/");
header("Location: http://site.ru/siteaccess.php");
exit();
}
```

В файле siteaccess.php замените проверку на:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookname'])) {
```

Comment: Заменил на то, что вы посоветовали - также безрезультатно. Мне вообще не удается перейти на siteaccess.php, то есть никак не получается пройти проверку условия.

Comment: Я снова опубликовал код со всеми исправлениями, пожалуйста посмотрите.

Comment: Отредактировал свой ответ.

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, я свой ответ выше поправил. Проблема заключалась в том, что в самом начале (файла setcookie1.php) были html-комментарии. Я их удалил, и скрипт сработал верно. Мне не пришлось включать ваши исправления. Пожалуйста, аргументируйте свои правки: почему, например, вы совсем убрали переменную  `$formDisplay`? Кроме того, почему вы решили заменить конструкцию проверки функцией isset с соответствующими параметрами?

Comment: 1) Некорректно делать редирект через html тег, если это можно сделать через php и при этом предотвратить загрузку всего документа. В вашем варианте получалось, так, что после авторизации загружался весь htmk документ и шел редирект, через header и exit я сделал это сразу и без лишней нагрузки. 2) У вас файл отвечает только за то, что был ли юзер авторизован или нет, для этого достаточно сделать проверку куки, если перед вами не стоит задача определить, что он был авторизован прямо сейчас (из-за чего вы передавали auth через GET)

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Получается, при работе с куками вообще необходимо исключить любой вывод, даже html-комментарии. То же касается и комментарий, которые я заключу в синтаксис  `<?php .... ?> ?`